# Deleting Ubuntu

Tags: format, permanent-delete

I have tried to format the hard drive but I can't!

I have tried to use the Disk Management option that says format, but it won't let me as it says it's busy. I can't install Windows as the hard drive is in the wrong format.

Help, please.

Answer (score -1):

Try booting computer with Windows disc and format the drive in setup.

Comment: Talk me through it please im beyond novice

Comment: I have booted the comp and attempted to install windows 7, but it just says cant install as wrong format and windows is not compatable. Windows was on this comp prior to putting unbuntu on., The comp got a awful virus and we sent it away to be fixed. Hence the unbuntu being on

Comment: You need to delete the partition first. Please give me detailed error message.